# How to send value from viewController to TabBar views in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift2

I have an `Swift app (xCode 7.1)`. I need send a value from a first viewController that contains a tableView to the two viewControllers into a TabBar Controller:

```
ViewController   -> Tabbar   -{ViewControllerTabBarView1
                             -{ViewControllerTabBarView2
```

I call the tabBar controller from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
 let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTab")

    self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)
```

All this is correct, but the values to pass from click into row to respective viewController of TabBar not work calling from didSelectRowAtIndexPath. This is null

```
 let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view1TabBar") as! EventoToDoController
    viewController.finca = (parsed.valueForKey("id")[indexPath.row] as? String)!
```

How can I send this values?

Comment: Try to access the tabbed viewController using `vc ` using `selectedViewController ` or `viewControllers ` by passing correct index for that viewController.

Comment: I can't access to the value using vc.viewControllers[1]